# SharePoint 2013 on-premises external access

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication, extranet

I'm using SharePoint 2013 On Premise for a project site.

I want Internal and External users will need to access to this site.

I am planning to enable FBA on this site for the External users.

If possible, I need a step by step guide on how to expose this site using a reverse proxy in DMZ zone, especially on SharePoint site.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried below mentioned solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enable FBA in your SharePoint site than please follow steps in below mentioned link.

1. [Configuring SharePoint 2013 Forms-Based Authentication with SQLMemberShipProvider](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/)
2. [Configuring Forms Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/)

You can understand the concept of using a reverse proxy by following link

[Securing External SharePoint Communications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.insidesharepoint.aspx)

Comment: thank you for the replay. Tried to search for step by step guid from the SharePoint side With no success. apperciate any help you can provid.

Comment: From SharePoint Side means?

Comment: This is the way how you can configure FBA in your SharePoint Environment